Getting an error when I am trying to use pre-built contract model on AI Document Intelligence Studio. Error code in the body
I was trying to analyze a contract using Microsoft's Document Intelligence Studio. All the pre-built models are working except for the contract pre-built model. I am getting error code:
"ModelNotFound The requested model was not found. apim-request-id: 37169394-5888-483d-9523-ce6a5409f50f"
which when I googled did not bring any relevant results. I have attached an image of the error from my perspective. Please help.
I was hoping to use the document intelligence studio and used the sample contract that microsoft itself has put on the studio but got the aforementioned error.
I used the invoice model, tax w2 model, credit card model, and they all work perfectly. It is just the pre-built contract model that throws up this error. Googling the error code brings up nothing. Please help.


I am getting error code:
"ModelNotFound The requested model was not found. apim-request-id: 37169394-5888-483d-9523-ce6a5409f50f"

Even I got the same error while using a sample Pre-built contract Model - Run analysis.


Here Microsoft only declared it was in progress (coming soon). When you see at the right side of the screen and then click on code.



It will typically now to access them through the platform's interface. But, through SDK we can access it. please follow this doc


While using SDK you need the key and endpoint of the service resource for this you need to create a resource in the azure portal search document intelligence and create. After creating navigate to the resource management and you can find keys and endpoint to get access.

